# UITableViewCell text disappearing on selection

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uilabel

I have a custom UITableView Cell which uses a custom view called **GradientView** for the **backgroundView** of the cell. it is set in the  **if (cell == nil)** function.
I had an issue with the contents of the cell duplicating to other cells, so I added the programic label creation to GradientView. I simply used **[self addSubview:label];** to add it. I also had a gradient that is drawn on self.layer. here is the full source for GradientView: http://pastie.org/2308803

The labels are set from the root view controller, by specifying their tag.
They display fine in the tableview, but when I highlight a cell, the cell goes completely blue. the lables ar invisible, all you see is blue. When you deselect it is back to normal.
Could someone please help me with this issue?